# C# .NET image not respecting the shown width and height

Tags: c#, .net, image

I am using Visual Studio 2019, C# Windows Forms.

```
        private void mainPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            var g = e.Graphics;

            Image image = Image.FromFile(path);
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
        }
```

With this code I would expect to see an image and a black rectangle around it. Instead, I am seeing this:
[image: Code result image]

Is this a weird bug or am I doing something wrong? I couldn't find anything about this on the internet.

Note: For other images it is working fine.

Comment: I checked your code, everything works fine, could you send the original image?

Comment: Most likely the dpi of the image != dpi of screen. Use `image.SetResolution(g.DpiX, g.DpiY)` to fix..!